# Wait for python script to return 0

Tags: python, sh

I'am  trying to write a script that is waiting for a database to be online.
The script that checks the database connection is written in python and should be excited every 5 seconds. If the script returns 0 the main script should continue.

I have never written in shell, so i can only guess how to get the python script into the condition of the while loop. Here is my attempt, but i have no idea how to get it right.

The python script is working well.

psqltest.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
#
import psycopg2
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgis' user='postgres' host='db' password='postgres'")
except:
    exit(1)

exit(0)
```

my main shell script:

```
echo waiting for database...
while  [ python /root/psqltest.py && echo 0 || echo 1 ]
  do
     sleep 5
  done
```

the error message:

```
 1 ]
```

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: OT, but do you have a good reason to be using python 2.4?

Comment: not really, i think i can use python 3 as well

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to code the loop in Python and just have it return control to the shell script when there connection was successful?

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking humans to debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell script would simply be

```
while ! python /root/psqltest.py; do
    sleep 5
done
```

or the lesser known

```
until python /root/psqltest.py; do
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved my Scripts, now the bash is only calling the python script and waits for it to finish, as Kristof mentioned. This is working so far, but i try to improve it further more.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
import psycopg2
import time
import sys

db = None
sys.stdout.write('waiting ')
while db is None:
  try:
      db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgis' user='postgres' host='db' password='...'")
      db.close()
  except:
      sys.stdout.write('.')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep( 5 )
print('')
exit(0)
```